# Error 13 "type mismatch" for if

Tags: vba, excel

I am making a game of rock-paper-scissors and I am getting stuck on the scoring code. All I want is when someone wins the score is displayed on a table on a different worksheet that is the data source for a graph that will be a scoreboard.

The code is:

```
If Worksheets("Game").Range("D5:E7").Value = "Rock" And Worksheets("Game").Range("D9:E11").Value = "Paper" Then Worksheets("Game Data").Range("F9").Value = Worksheets("Game Data").Range("F9").Value + 1
If Worksheets("Game").Range("D5:E7").Value = "Rock" And Worksheets("Game").Range("D9:E11").Value = "Scissors" Then Worksheets("Game Data").Range("F8").Value = Worksheets("Game Data").Range("F8").Value + 1
If Worksheets("Game").Range("D5:E7").Value = "Paper" And Worksheets("Game").Range("D9:E11").Value = "Scissors" Then Worksheets("Game Data").Range("F9").Value = Worksheets("Game Data").Range("F9").Value + 1
If Worksheets("Game").Range("D5:E7").Value = "Paper" And Worksheets("Game").Range("D9:E11").Value = "Rock" Then Worksheets("Game Data").Range("F8").Value = Worksheets("Game Data").Range("F8").Value + 1
If Worksheets("Game").Range("D5:E7").Value = "Scissors" And Worksheets("Game").Range("D9:E11").Value = "Rock" Then Worksheets("Game Data").Range("F9").Value = Worksheets("Game Data").Range("F9").Value + 1
If Worksheets("Game").Range("D5:E7").Value = "Scissors" And Worksheets("Game").Range("D9:E11").Value = "Paper" Then Worksheets("Game Data").Range("F8").Value = Worksheets("Game Data").Range("F8").Value + 1
```

When I run it I get error 13 type mismatch. I don't know what I am doing wrong! Can anyone help?

Comment: You could make your code more readable and less repetitive if you had an object (Range) pointing to the cells involved.

Comment: `Range("D5:E7").Value` would be an array, so it would generated error if you compare it with string `"Rock"`  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using merged cells as your ranges are referencing multiple cells. This leads you to be comparing an array of values to a single string hence the type mismatch. If this is the case then the value of the merged cells is stored in the first cell in the merged cells and you can try the following modification shown for your first if statement (line continuation _ added to make the code easier to read).

```
If Worksheets("Game").Range("D5").Value = "Rock" And _ 
Worksheets("Game").Range("D9").Value = "Paper" Then _
Worksheets("Game Data").Range("F9").Value = _
Worksheets("Game Data").Range("F9").Value + 1
```

You will need to modify each line in order to stop the type missmatch errors.

Comment: thanks for your response. yes, i was using merged cells and yes, it works. thanks again!